# Counterexamples to LIATE without integration by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to find a counterexample to the LIATE rule to demonstrate to students.

The ones I've found ($x^3e^{x^2}, \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}$, etc) are all examples where part of the integrand is a substitution integration in disguise and integrating by parts following the LIATE order destroys that substitution. I personally find this less satisfying.

I'm wondering if there are any examples where the integral is a straightforward integration by parts but is difficult or impossible using the LIATE order.

Comment: Take a look at Phil's answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620724/when-is-liate-simply-wrong I hope it helps

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar This is also example of integration by substitution exactly the same as my example of $x^3e^{x^2}$.

Comment: To be fair, that's technically  a recognizing quotient rule problem, I think

Comment: @JohnLou The $x^3\sin x^2$ and the $\frac{xe^x}{(1+x)^2}$ one are both the same as the ones I listed above (and $\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$ isn't even a polynomial before substitution).

Comment: Fair enough. If I recall correctly, sometimes LIATE is taught as ILATE, so that might lead you in a satisfactory direction.

Comment: @JohnLou Logarithmic and inverse trig functions have the exact same issue where their derivatives are significantly simpler than themselves. Same with trig and exponential (derivatives being very similar to themselves). The LI and TE are both interchangeable already and I taught it as such.

Comment: @user297884 I would wager that if LIATE cannot be used for a given (solvable) integral, there is an easier way to find the antiderivative.

Comment: @JohnLou Of course--I'm fine with one that can be solved by other means, but I wanted to demonstrate a case where the LIATE _order_ does not work, but integrating by parts out of order, without proceeding with subsitution, works.

Comment: Discussing idiosyncratic acronyms used only in some universities in some countries is not yet mathematics. Mathematics starts with definitions.

Comment: I believe using LIATE needs a comprehensive perspective and if so, there seems to be no counterexample. For instance, if you see $\int{x^3\sin{x^2}dx}$ (where LIATE does not work), as $\int{x^2 \cdot x\sin{x^2}dx}$ then you can use LIATE.

Comment: Anyway, if you are still insisting on your question, as you are instructing to students, I suggest you ask them to find the counterexamples which will be solved without substitution as a bonus question. This makes them also encourages them to enrich their research skills for future academic studies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting example I came across:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$

If you choose $u = \dfrac{x}{(1+2x)^2}$ (which is what LIATE would choose) for the integration by parts, things are going to get messy, but if you choose $u = xe^{2x}$, then it simplifies quite nicely.